# Zipping and reshaping in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Problem:

Let's say I have two tensors, `a` and `b`. Both have the same shape: `[?, 10, 4096]`.

How do I zip the two in a manner that the resulting tensor has a shape of [?, 20, 4096], **but also** such that the *ith* element of `a` comes right before the *ith* element of `b`.

Example with lists:

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = [2, 4, 6]
```

and now I want a tensor that looks like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and **not** `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]`, which is what would happen if I were to `tf.stack` the two and then use `tf.reshape`, right?.

Or perhaps a more general question would be, how do you know in what order `tf.reshape` reshapes a tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it looks like, stacking and then reshaping does the job:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1, 3, 5])
b = tf.constant([2, 4, 6])
c = tf.stack([a, b], axis = 1)
d = tf.reshape(c, (-1,)) 
with tf.Session() as sess:    
     print(sess.run(c))  # [[1 2],[3 4],[5 6]]
     print(sess.run(d))  # [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

To answer your second question, TensorFlow `reshape` operation use the same order than `numpy` default order, a.k.a `C` order, quoting from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> Read the elements of a using this index order, and place the elements into the reshaped array using this index order. ‘C’ means to read / write the elements using C-like index order, with the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first axis index changing slowest.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 3, 5])
b = np.array([2, 4, 6])
c = np.stack([a, b], axis=1)
c.reshape((-1,), order='C')  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```